# Bash: process substitution inside a string

Tags: bash, bash4

In bash if I type a command `foo bar <(qux)` it will launch the foo program and its parameters will be `bar` and `/dev/fd/63` (or something like that).

If I type a command `foo "bar <(qux)"` it will launch the foo program and its parameter will be `bar <(qux)`.

How can I lauch foo with a single parameter `bar /dev/fd/63`?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you even want to do this? Seems pretty odd.

Comment: That being said the solution seems pretty clear to me. Just recall that the shell splits on whitespace and you can put quotes wherever you want.

Comment: @danfuzz I want this, because I have a shell script that downloads TS video stream from web and spits it to stdout. And I want to play it in my program that accepts as a parameter a part of GStreamer pipeline. I want to launch `my_player "filesrc location="<(my_script)" ! decodebin" ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change quoting little bit:

```
foo "bar "<(qux)
```

Comment: Stack overflow answers have been great treasure for me ;)